# Error Python tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating the Python tkinter program that access user enter for value. Then user will choose options which include Fahrenheit or Celsius from radio buttons. There will the message shows which choice user chose and when pressing calculate button the new converted Fahrenheit or Celsius value will be display on the label behind Calculate button. 
I build the program base on View Model Control and when I execute main program which is Control program I have followed error:

```
AttributeError: 'Calculate' object has no attribute 'radioButtonShowChoice'
```

I have 3 separated files which are for View Model Control architecture
Firts one is named frame for view:

```
import tkinter
class AppFrame(tkinter.Frame):
    """
    class AppFrame is the View for a simple program converts between temperature
    in Fareinheit and tempterature in Celicus
    """
    def __init__(self, controller):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)   # initializes the superclass
        self.pack()   #  required in order for the Buttons to show up properly
        self.controller = controller
        v = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.titleLabel1 = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.titleLabel1["text"] = "Fahrenheit and Celcius converter program"
        self.titleLabel1.pack()

        self.titleLabel2 = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.titleLabel2["text"] = "Enter your value here:"
        self.titleLabel2.pack({"fill":"x","padx":"10"})

        self.entryData = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entryData.pack({"fill":"x","padx":"10"})

        self.titleLabel3 = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.titleLabel3["text"] = "Choose options bellow:"
        self.titleLabel3.pack({"fill":"x","padx":"10"})

        self.radioButton1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self,text="Fahreinheit", variable = v, value =1 )
        self.radioButton1["command"] = self.controller.radioButtonShowChoice
        self.radioButton1.pack({"anchor":"w"})

        self.radioButton2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self,text="Celcius", variable = v, value = 2)
        self.radioButton2["command"] = self.controller.radioButtonShowChoice
        self.radioButton2.pack({"anchor":"w"})

        self.resultLabel1 = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.titleLabel1.pack({"fill":"x","padx":"10"})

        self.calculateButton = tkinter.Button(self)
        self.calculateButton["text"] = "CALCULATE"
        self.calculateButton["command"] = self.controller.buttonCalculate
        self.calculateButton.pack({"fill":"x","padx":"10"})

        self.resultLabel2 = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.titleLabel2.pack({"fill":"x","padx":"10"})
```

Second one is named calculate for Model

```
import tkinter
import frame
class Calculate:
    """
    Class Calculate is the Model for calculating the convert to Fahreinheit or Celcius
    It also displays the result on the screen
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.newValue = 0
        self.view = frame.AppFrame(self)

    def displayChoice(self):
        if str(self.view.v.get()) == "1":
            return "You chose option 1 for Fahreinheit converter"
        elif str(self.view.v.get()) == "2":
            return "You chose option 2 for Celcius converter"

    def displayResult(self):
        if str(self.view.v.get()) == "1":
            self.newValue = (9/5 * int(self.view.entryData.get())) + 32
        elif str(self.view.v.get()) == "2":
            self.newValue = 5/9 * (int(self.view.entryData.get()) - 32)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.newValue)
```

The last one is main program which is named myMain for Controller

```
import tkinter
import frame
import calculate

class Display:
    """
    The Display class for an app that follows the Model/View/Controller architecture.
    When the user presses the Button converter on the View, this Display calles the appropriate methods in the Model.
    """
    def __init__(self):       
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.model = calculate.Calculate()
        self.view = frame.AppFrame(self)
        self.view.mainloop()
        root.destroy()

    def radioButtonShowChoice(self):
        self.view.resultlabel1["text"] = self.model.displayChoice

    def buttonCalculate(self):
        self.model.displayResult()
        self.view.resultLabel2["text"] = "The new value of tempreature is "+str(self.model
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = Display()
```

Any helps to make this program work will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `Display.__init__(self)`

```
self.model = calculate.Calculate()
```

In `Calculate.__init__(self)`

```
self.view = frame.AppFrame(self)
```

In `AppFrame.__init__(self, controller)`

```
self.controller = controller
...

self.radioButton1["command"] = self.controller.radioButtonShowChoice
self.radioButton2["command"] = self.controller.radioButtonShowChoice
```

`self.controller` is the value passed to the `AppFrame` constructor, which was a Calculate object.  You are trying to assign `radioButtonShowChoice` which is not an attribute in `Calculate`, as the error message indicates.  I assume you want to assign the function from `Display`.  You are also creating two `AppFrame`'s which is confusing to me - one in the `Calculate` object, and one in the `Display` object.

In your implementation, `AppFrame` needs a function from `Display`, so `AppFrame` at some point needs a reference to `Display` - The first one created from inside Calculate does not have that reference.

```
Calculate - AppFrame instance #1
Display - AppFrame instance #2, Calculate object
AppFrame #1 - Calculate as the controller
AppFrame #2 - Display as the controller
```

Finally, somewhere with that error message should have been a stack trace pointing you to a line number where the error occurred.  That is *really* important.